# How to create a loop or something that can help me to calculate autoarima, smooth, tbats, and other models of time series to 47 columns

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, forecast

I am trying to forecast profits of different products (
about 50). In my data frame, the products are columns and I have one column with the dates. Every row corresponds to the profits in a single day. I am trying to use ARIMA, NAIVe, SES, TBAT for every column but I do not how to do it without writing 50 lines of code.

The code for one column

```
##Serie de tiempo de Personales

personales <- ts(intereses$Personales, start = c(2020,1), end = c(2022,12), frequency =12)

##Modelo ARIMA Personales
   arima_personales <- auto.arima(personales)
##Proyección por los siguientes 12 meses 
   forecast(arima_personales, h=12)
   summary(arima_personales)
##Graficando las proyecciones
   plot(forecast(arima_personales,12), xlab="Data Mensual", ylab="Ingresos financieros por intereses        Personales", main ="Ingresos financieros por intereses", col.main = "darkblue")
 
##Modelo NAÏVE Personales
   naive_personales <- naive(personales, h=12)
   summary(naive_personales)
##Gráfica
  plot(naive_personales, xlab="Data Mensual", ylab="Ingresos financieros por intereses Personales", main ="Ingresos financieros por intereses", col.main = "darkblue")

##Suavizamiento Exponencial Personales
  se_personales <- ses(personales, h=12)
  summary(se_personales)
##Gráfica
  plot(se_personales, xlab="Data Mensual", ylab="Ingresos financieros por intereses Personales", main ="Ingresos financieros por intereses", col.main = "darkblue")

##Modelo Holt's Winter Personales
  holt_personales <- holt(personales, h=12)
  summary(holt_personales)
##Gráfica
  plot(holt_personales, xlab="Data Mensual", ylab="Ingresos financieros por intereses Personales", main ="Ingresos financieros por intereses", col.main = "darkblue")

##Modelo TBATS
  tbats_personales <- forecast(tbats(personales), h=12)
   summary(tbats_personales)
```

and the CODE for all the columns:

```
##Creando las series de tiempo de cada columna
  intereses_ts <- ts(data=intereses[-1],start = c(2020,1), end = c(2022,12), frequency =12)

##Graficando las series de tiempo
  ts.plot(intereses_ts, col = 1:46, xlab = "Cierre de mes", ylab = "Ingresos", main = "Ingresos por intereses")
  legend("topleft", colnames(intereses_ts), lty=1, col=1:46, bty = "n")


##Modelo ARIMA
  for (i in 1:ncol(intereses_ts)) {
  paste("arima_",name(intereses_ts[,i]))<- auto.arima(intereses_ts[,i])
}
```

Comment: You would find the fable package easier -- designed to forecast many serious simultaneously. fable.tidyverts.org

Comment: Hi Rob, how are you? Thank you so much. Fable is also for multiple variables time series? Fable is for all the time series model?